# Windows Server 2008 hangs up while booting

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Windows Server 2008 hangs up while booting after Windows update applied several updates.  The server is a virtual instance on a Server 2008 Hyper-V host.  Other virtual servers are fine, but have not been updated.

The normal boot shows the horizontal barber poll forever.
When I do a safe boot  it also hangs up.  With a "Please Wait..." after loading many '.sys' files.

The last successfully loaded file listed is: '\Windows\system32\drivers\crcdisk.sys'

That is the extent of what I have been able to determine.

Comment: Ping me at my firstname dot lastname at microsoft.com and I'll get you in touch with someone who can help troubleshoot, and we can post the resolution once we have one.

Comment: Awesome offer of assistance. Restores my faith in mankind ;)

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Never pinged me :p

Comment: Two years later, I note that there's no resolution, and I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Are there any services that are taking their time starting that is maybe delaying things?

Comment: @SeanM Have you tried Safe Mode with Boot Logging enabled. Perhaps, some interesting facts show up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to uninstall updates using [Microsoft Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532075.aspx) version 6.0 or 6.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2).