# Windows Server 2008 Hangs On Boot After crcdisk.sys

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm running a Windows 2008 Server install that's been having trouble. It's had several anomalous reboots, and finally got stuck in a state where it couldn't finish booting. When I attempt to boot into Safe Mode, the last driver that appears before the process freezes is `\Windows\system32\drivers\crcdisk.sys`.

How can I restore/overrwrite a file so that the machine boots again - or am I just out of luck on this?

As a note, I already tried booting from the install media and running `StartRep.exe` - it claimed to have repaired something, but the problem persisted and there was no visible change.

It's sad that there are so many unanswered questions out there that are about pretty much this circumstance. There are even tragedies like [a question right here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/91255/windows-server-2008-hangs-up-while-booting) with a Microsoft employee promising an answer, then failing to produce one. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that the file isn't corrupt, but the part of the disk that it sits on are. I'd boot to a command prompt from recovery media and run `chkdsk c:\ /r` and see if that finds and fixes bad sectors and successfully relocates them.

Comment: I ran a quick scan with SpinRite, if you're familiar with that, that came back without reporting any errors. I am not sure how much of the same territory chkdsk.exe covers - should I still bother ?

Comment: I have no idea what SpinRite is. Is it capable of reading the NTFS journal and correcting inconsistencies?

Comment: No it is not - so if chkdsk is capable of that, as you imply, I'd better try it.

Comment: Yeah, I would. Chkdsk is the official Microsoft tool for validating and repairing disk consistencies. I'd definitely give that a whirl.

Comment: Chkdsk got stuck on file N out of a few hundred thousand for 16+ hours, so I'm calling that a failed drive, I think.  :(

Comment: Probably a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be a problem loading the disk driver, what kind of disk configuration do you have ?

However when i faced this kind of error on a Windows Vista workstation was that the operating system was installed with the disk configuration in compatibility mode and a blackout restored the default configuration to AHCI on the BIOS settings, so unless you change back disk configuration you keep getting the system hanged on crcdisk.sys.

Could be a driver issue with the disk/s also in your situation ...

Comment: This is a machine that had been running fine for a year or so, so I doubt that it's a driver issue, and I don't think that the BIOS settings have been changed - I looked through them while troubleshooting. Couldn't hurt to look again, though.

Answer (score -1):

Check your power supply is not faulty.  I spent days scouring the internet and trying different software and hardware solutions.  It turned out to be a faulty power supplt